# Enable Button In ListView WPF When Selected Item and enable selected item's button

Tags: wpf

I have a list view that contain in every items is a button, I want when user click on Item and which button of item which selected to Enable in MVVM! Sorry for my bad English!
This is my Xaml Code:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListSupplier}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItems, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
                            <ListView.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </ListView.Resources>
                            <ListView.View>
                                <GridView>
                                    <GridViewColumn
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}"
                                    Header="ID" />
                                    <GridViewColumn
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DisplayName}"
                                    Header="Nhà cung cấp" />
                                    <GridViewColumn
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Address}"
                                    Header="Địa chỉ" />
                                    <GridViewColumn
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Phone}"
                                    Header="Số điện thoại" />
                                    <GridViewColumn
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ContractDay}"
                                    Header="Thời gian hợp tác" />
                                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Chức Năng">
                                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Button x:Name="Button_Edit" DataContext="{StaticResource SupplierViewModel}" 
                                                        Command="{Binding EditCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Button_Edit}" 
                                                        Content="Sửa" Width="100"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn>
                                </GridView>
                            </ListView.View>
                        </ListView>
```

This is my EditCommand in SupplierViewModel:

```
EditCommand = new RelayCommand<Button>((p) =>
            {
                /*var Supplier = DataProvider.Ins.Entities.SupplierTable.Where(x => x.DisplayName == DisplayName);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DisplayName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Phone) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Address) || ContractDay == null)
                    return false;

                if (Supplier == null || SelectedItems == null)
                    return false;
                if(p != null)
                {
                    p.IsEnabled = true;
                    return true ;
                }
                return false*/ //Comment
                return false;
            }, (p) =>
            {
                var Supplier = DataProvider.Ins.Entities.SupplierTable.Where(x => x.DisplayName == DisplayName);
                if (Supplier == null || SelectedItems == null)
                {
                    p.IsEnabled = false; 
                    return;
                }
                SelectedItems.

                SupplierTable EditItem = DataProvider.Ins.Entities.SupplierTable.Where(x=>x.ID == SelectedItems.ID).SingleOrDefault();
                if(EditItem == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                EditItem.DisplayName = DisplayName;
                EditItem.Address = Address;
                EditItem.ContractDay = ContractDay;
                EditItem.Phone = Phone;

                DataProvider.Ins.Entities.SaveChanges();
                ListSupplier = new List<SupplierTable>(DataProvider.Ins.Entities.SupplierTable);

                DisplayName = null;
                Address = null;
                Phone = null;
                ContractDay = DateTime.Today;
                SelectedItems = null;

                IsActiveSnackBar = true;
                Message = "Sửa Thành Công!";

                System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                timer.Interval = 3000;
                timer.Enabled = true;
                timer.Elapsed += ShowSnackBar;
                timer.Start();
            });
```

I don't know how to find the button in listview what is selected, i want the button in list item which selected will enable and the other is disable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XAML is setting the IsEnabled property on the button if the ListViewItem is selected.

You have to add the Command part again to do something when the button is clicked on.

```
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <Button x:Name="Button_Edit" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsSelected, 
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}"
                                    Width="100" Content="Sửa"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It work! Can i do same with textbox?

Comment: I have try my question and it works! Thank you so much!